ADF Get response header
The web activity in the Azure data factory returns response with the part like this

I need to access that 'Set-Cookie' value.
So, I attempt this
@activity('Set Cookie').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders.Set-Cookie
)

or

The error is shown as red underline, and I don't understand what it is.
Also, when running the pipeline, I get the error


ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The expression 'activity('Set Cookie').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders.Set-Cookie
)' is not valid: the string character 'C' at position '64' is not expected."



If I do this (stopping before 'Set-Cookie',
@activity('Set Cookie').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders
    )

I get the full ADFWebActivityResonseHeaders as string.  How to drill down to a single element ?

I have tried your scenario, with a sample key and I got the same error.

The above occurs at triggered pipeline runs. It is due to the special characters in the key value. If you try to only debug the pipeline, it will give bad request error and at trigger level it will give the above error.
To resolve the above error and to specify the values for the keys which have special characters, you can enclose the key  in the [] like this ['<key_value>'].
A sample demo:
@activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['<key_name>']


Result:


thank you.  It works well.  I came close with using it as <.'key'>which did not work ... did not think about '[]'
Interestingly, that in this regard it works similar as if in sql server using a column with the special characters'.
Thanks again

Glad it worked out for you : ).
